# Can I programmatically delete existing duplicate Leads in my lead object?

Tags: leads

I came to a  recent scenario where i have 10,000 existing leads in my lead object. I want to delete the existing  duplicate leads which have duplicate emails in my lead object. So that the anonymous emails cant be sent . i have wrote a trigger but its not working. Help me out.

Comment: Trigger is not the solution for this but what's your trigger it may help us in understanding how are you identifying duplicate leads

Comment: @Bennie i wrote a trigger but  when we create a new lead then it prevent from duplicate. but i want to check for the existing records.

Comment: You have to use appexchange products for this maybe DemandTools doing it using apex is also a manual task depending on the criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Mass Delete](https://ap1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_massdelete_undoimport.pdf) functionality to undo any imports.

Follow [this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gx2RAAQ) link or below provided steps

> 1. Click Your Name | Setup | Data Management | Mass Delete Records.
> 2. Click the link for the type of record to delete.
> 3. Review the information that will be deleted along with the records.
> 4. Specify conditions that the selected items must match, for example, “State equals California.” For more information, seeEntering Filter
>      Criteria.
> 5. When deleting accounts, check the appropriate boxes if you want to delete accounts with attached closed/won opportunities or attached
>      opportunities owned by other users.
> 6. When deleting products, check Archive Products... if you want to include products that are on opportunities. Archived products are not
>      moved to the Recycle Bin. Check this option to:
>
>    - Delete products that are not on opportunities and move them to the Recycle Bin.
>    - Archive products that are on opportunities. These products are not moved to the Recycle Bin and cannot be recovered.
>
> Leave this box unchecked to delete only those products that are not on
>   opportunities. Selected products that are on opportunities will remain
>   checked after the deletion to indicate they were not included in the
>   deletion.
>
> 7. Choose Search to find records that match.
> 8. Select the box next to the items you want to delete. Optionally, check the box in the column header to select all currently displayed
>      items.
> 9. To permanently delete records, select Permanently delete the selected records. Please note that selecting this option prevents you
>      from recovering the selected records from the Recycle Bin.
> 10. Click Delete. If you did not select Permanently delete the selected records, deleted items are moved to the Recycle Bin.

You can use 3rd party tools for removing duplicates, refer [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54163/deduping-existng-leads-and-contacts) thread for more details.

Comment: sir  i know this  Mass Delete Functionality but my question  is that  it is not possible through   controller?